# Como atualizar uma listview a partir do botão do action bar

Tags: android, listview

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para atualizar uma `listView` a partir de um botão na *action bar*. Ao clicar esta seria atualizada pegando os dados novamente do site https://parse.com. Esta `listview` pega dados do site https://parse.com e faz a implementação dos dados.

Estou utilizando os métodos: `RemoteDataTask` `AsyncTask` e o `onPostExecute`.

Código do Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_ofertas, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
            .getPopulation());
    // Set the results into ImageView
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag(),
            holder.flag);

    return view;
  }

}
```

Comment: É andorid certo?

Comment: @Fernando não sei se é Android...

Comment: Opa  @JorgeB., `ListView`, `ActionBar`, `AsyncTask` e `onPostExecute`, não sei se outras tecnologias tem "componentes" com estes mesmo nome? Mas podemos desfazer a edição no caso de duvida, e esperar o AP se pronunciar.

Comment: @Fernando Deixa ficar, mal não vai fazer. Eu também coloquei a tag mas depois tirei. Deixa ficar assim e depois vê-se.

Comment: Eh Android sim. Era essa a duvida?

Comment: @Jorge B. Eh Android sim o que estou utilizando, e estou com essa duvida para atualizar minha listview a partir de um botao na action bar.

Comment: Era só para editar a sua pergunta com a tag Android, que já está. Mas não sei responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: @Jorge B. Entendi desculpa. Teria como atualizar a activity a partir do botão na action bar? Pq tbm ajudaria.

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você já criou um arquivo xml para os itens do menu e que você já determinou que sua Action Bar utilizará este arquivo para gerar os itens de menu, o próximo passo será determinar o que acontece quando cada elemento do menu da Action Bar é clicado. Isso se faz da seguinte maneira:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Trata cliques nos itens da Action Bar
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.opcao_1_do_menu:

                //Código para o clique na opcao 1
                return true;

            case R.id.opcao_atualizar_lista:

                // Código para atualizar a lista
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

No caso do código para atualizar a **List View**, a melhor abordagem seria atualizar somente o **Adapter**(que contem os dados) e notificar à **List View** a qual ele está associado de que os dados foram modificados e portanto a **List View** precisa ser atualizada. Para fazer isso execute o seguinte método após inserir/remover/atualizar dados no seu **Adapter**:

```
meuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Este método poderia ficar dentro do método que pega os dados do site. Por exemplo, suponha que na sua activity tenha um método `public void pegarDados()`, que acessa o site, pega os dados e os recebe como uma lista de Dados. Assim, após receber essa lista, você deve adicionar os dados da lista no adapter.

```
public void pegarDados(){

    List<Dados> listaDados = suaListaDeDadosDoSite;

    for(Dado d : listaDados){

        meuAdapter.add(Dado);
    }

    meuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
}
```

**Perceba que**:

- Você terá que criar um método `public void add(Dado)` no seu ListAdapter.
- Se a sua lista de dados recebida do site tiver elementos que já existam no adapter atual, então você terá que instanciar um novo adapter dentro de `public void pegaDados()`, ao invés de adicionar os elementos recebidos no adapter atual.

Comment: Olá amigo obrigado pela resposta, editei o primeiro código utilizando apenas um case, pois tenho apenas um botão na ActionBar, mas esta segunda parte do `meuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Não consegui identificar onde posso colocar ele, na pergunta coloquei a informação da minha Class ListViewAdapter. Onde eu poderia inserir esse código?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta para responder melhor :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar, veja só tentei da forma que você falou mas não consegui, daí resolvi fazer sozinho buscando no código algo que eu pudesse utilizar para chamar essa ação que iniciada assim que o app é aberto:

```
new RemoteDataTask().execute();
```

Porém ao analisar isso, vi a necessidade de chamar ele novamente a partir do botão de refresh que tenho no meu ACTION BAR, e também foi isso que fiz:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Trata cliques nos itens da Action Bar
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon_refresh:
            new RemoteDataTask().execute(); //ISSO AQUI FOI FUNDAMENTAL, chamado novamente para carregar os dados do site parse.com

            //Código para o clique na opcao 1
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

@regmoraes. Obrigado por todas as dicas e tentativas de solucionar meu problema. Show! Funcionando perfeitamente!